# Nested columns in panel heading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted my panel heading to contain some text and a button, the former being left-aligned and the latter, right-aligned. But as soon as I apply the class `row` to my panel header, it breaks out of the parent div and takes up what I believe to be the container width.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading row">
        <h4 class="col-md-11">Manage Your Subscriptions</h4>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default col-md-1" >Log out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the result:

[image]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me like you just need to move the "row" to be inside the "panel-heading" rather than on the same level, as they both have relative CSS positioning properties. I tried the following code:

```
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="col-md-11">Manage Your Subscriptions</h4>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" >Log out</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Stackoverflow rocks!
        </div>
    </div>
```

and it gave me this output (which is what you're looking for, I hope):
[image]

I hope that helps

EDIT: I tried using "pull-right" as others have suggested and it seems to create more troubles as it messes the top/bottom margins as well since it makes the display block relative to container (Which I would generally recommend against doing, even if it works for you).

EDIT2: moved the "col-md-1" class into an encapsulating "div" to solve the button's margins' issue.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. My only complaint now is that the button is pasted too fat on the right. How do I remedy that? Good-old padding/margin?

Comment: Yes, good-ol padding would do the trick. I suggest making a new simple css  class to add the margin needed and have the "div" (which is wrapping the button) tag use it. You're welcome by the way, glad that I could help.

Comment: @MarwanAlani just want to understand why do say that `pull-right` causes troubles. From my point of view, your solution does not render fine if the text inside the button is longer. Moreover the button appers on the left side, if the screen is smaller than 768px.

Comment: @VincenzoC It's just in the case of the code OP provided above. However, with the sample you provided, it works perfectly. The general idea is to avoid using "pull" classes on navigation bars and headers in order to simplify upgradability in the future ("pull" classes doesn't work very well inside "collapse" for example). Either way, this is just my personal opinion and a best practice I noticed with time. It is not a rule by any means and you can use any design/tools you feel suitable when implementing something.

Comment: @MarwanAlani thank you very much for your explanation. I asked to understand if I was missing something. I'm using `pull-left` + `pull-right` + `clearfix` in my production code and I wanted to be sure that I'm not exposed to potential layout issues. Now I know that my solution is good and it does not break any rule.

Comment: @VincenzoC no problem at all, I'm always glad to learn and help :)

Answer (score 1):

May be you need something like following?

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <h4>Manage Your Subscriptions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" >Log out</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pull-left` and `pull-right` instead of grid system, so the components will be rendered on single line even on small screen (if there is enough space):

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="pull-left">Manage Your Subscriptions</h4>
        <span class="pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" >Log out</a>
        </span>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
</div>
```